UDP not working over wifi with two devices in python
I'm very new to UDP and I'm trying to connect two devices using python. They are both operating on the same network. I have written a code that works for the same device:
server:
import socket

# Create a UDP socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the server address and port
server_address = '192.168.1.1'  # Replace with the server's IP address
server_port = 12345
server_socket.bind((server_address, server_port))

print(f"Server is running on {server_address}:{server_port}")

try:
    while True:
        # Wait for a message
        print("\nWaiting to receive a message...")
        data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(4096)

        print(f"Received {len(data)} bytes from {address}")
        print(data.decode())

        if data:
            sent = server_socket.sendto(data, address)
            print(f"Sent {sent} bytes back to {address}")

finally:
    print("Closing the server socket")
    server_socket.close()

client:
import socket

# Create a UDP socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = '192.168.1.2'  # Replace with the server's IP address
server_port = 12345

try:
    # Send data
    message = 'This is the message. It will be echoed back!'
    print(f"Sending: {message}")
    sent = client_socket.sendto(message.encode(), (server_address, server_port))

    # Receive response
    print("Waiting to receive")
    data, server = client_socket.recvfrom(4096)
    print(f"Received: {data.decode()}")

finally:
    print("Closing the client socket")
    client_socket.close()

When I try to use the client code on a different machine with the same IP I get an error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop\client.py", line 9, in <module>
    server_socket.bind((server_address, server_port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"

How do I fix this issue?
Thank you very much for your time
Update: Setting the connection for both windows machines to private made the error dissapear, however now both machines are stuck on "receiving" message.

Why and where does client.py contain server_socket.bind(...?

Thanks for your input. I've updated the code on my client device and made the connection on both of them private (because they are windows). The error no longer shows but both machines are stuck on "waiting to receive"

What did you tried and searched over the internet before asking ? Sockets & UDP are very well documented over the internet for decades, and almost any language you could think of. Moreover, when dealing with socket error codes (on windows), one can have a look here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2

Does this answer your question? Errno 10049:creating UDP socket

(moreover, there are tons of quasi duplicates of this question and error code, example here /questions/36266109/errno-10049creating-udp-socket)

Ok managed to make it work.
First I made sure that both windows devices are discoverable in the network. I set them to private.
Secondly I added the port 12345 on my inbound and outbound ports.
Thirdly I changed the IP for both devices to be the same (the server IP). Although the code also works for when the server ip is set to empty ('')
